# Selecting unique values from more arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got the following code:

```
$get_countries = "SELECT country FROM blahs WHERE country IS NOT NULL ORDER BY country";
$data_get_countries = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_countries);

while ($row_get_countries = mysqli_fetch_array($data_get_countries)) {
    $country_tabs = array_unique($row_get_countries);
    foreach ($country_tabs as $country_tab) {
        echo '<div>' . $country_tab . '</div>';
        var_dump($country_tab);
        var_dump($country_tabs);

    }
}
```

For now the var_dump($country_tab) outputs:

```
string 'DE' (length=2)
string 'GB' (length=2)
string 'SE' (length=2)
string 'US' (length=2)
string 'US' (length=2)
string 'US' (length=2)
string 'US' (length=2)
```

and the var_dump($country_tabs):

```
array
    0 => string 'DE' (length=2)
array
    0 => string 'GB' (length=2)
array
    0 => string 'SE' (length=2)
array
    0 => string 'US' (length=2)
array
    0 => string 'US' (length=2)
array
    0 => string 'US' (length=2)
array
    0 => string 'US' (length=2)
```

The thing that I want to achieve is to make my code to not show the same countries!
array_unique($country_tabs) doesn't work because I have more arrays in the output.

Comment: [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) should work. That `var_dump()` is the output *after* you do an `array_unique()`?

Comment: It does work only for one array! I've tried to get all of those arrays in one but I didn't achieved what i want, I did it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off getting the unique values in the database query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM blahs WHERE country IS NOT NULL ORDER BY country
```

Note that I added the DISTINCT keyword to do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT country FROM blahs WHERE country IS NOT NULL ORDER BY country`

It will delete every duplicate value.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your query to get only unique countries:

```
$get_countries = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM blahs WHERE country IS NOT NULL ORDER BY country";
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the unique countries with the mysql query:

```
SELECT country 
FROM blahs 
WHERE country IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country
```

This is way more optimized!